# Spring boot skeleton from Swagger

Tags: spring, api, spring-boot, swagger

I was wondering if it's possible to generate a Spring boot skeleton from Swagger just like what restlet studio does.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen. It can generate Spring Stub and a number of other Java frameworks.

Comment: Thank you. Well it generates Spring skeleton and not Spring boot but with some slight modifications we can get what we want.